# Laravel Use Eloquent model from custom UserServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel, just toying with it and getting my head back into MVC.

I'm trying to make my own User auth provider (custom password hashing) as a service that implements the UserProviderInterface within Laravel.

Inside app/controllers/Account.php:

```
public function postCreate() {
    Auth::attempt(Input::all());
}
```

I have my app routing Auth::attempt through my custom provider class, and passing me the Input::all from the form into a retrieveByCredentials method.

Inside app/services/PasswordHash/PasswordHashUserProvider.php:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {
    // Why can't I do this?
    //Error: PasswordHash/User not found
    User::find($credentials['username']);

    dd($credentials);
}
```

I am lost at this point on how to access my User eloquent models from within this service class. I tried namespaces but had no luck.

Comment: Did you try `use use App\User;` ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work. I realized I should be passing a blank user model into my password class and calling methods off of it to create my user model. I have querying by username working now.

Answer (score 0):

The boot method on service providers use the service container to inject dependencies. To that end, you should be able to do the following (not using Facades, but I don't use facades that often).

```
class PasswordHashUserProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $user;

    public function boot(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

}
```

You can then access user via `$this->user`

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#the-boot-method